# Using Lookup on Dynamic block

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup, dynamic

Attempting to use this string within my dynamic content block with rules that are tied to `%%KeyField%%`. Looking to pinpoint where my issue is coming from and why it isn't working on test/live sends.

```
%%[

SET @EmailAddress = emailaddress

SET @KeyField = Lookup("DE Name","KeyField", "EmailAddress", @EmailAddress)

]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call it like this because it is a variable not a personalisation string

Calling it your way would only work if it was a profile attribute (for which you wouldn't need the lookup)

%%=v(@Keyfield)=%%

Resources:

- [Personalization Strings & Ampscript](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/personalization_strings_and_ampscript/)
- [V](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/v/#v)